# Tool to create list of fake email addresses

Tags: email, autocomplete

I would like to know:

1. If there is a tool to create a large list of fake email addresses to test an auto-complete. I want to test it with data the looks like it could be real..?
2. If somebody knows how large the list can be(approx) in memory for the auto-complete to still be functional using only Javascript on the browser. When will I need to do it using a database (server side)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mailinator.net addresses.These are temp mail addressed provided by mailinator.com to avoid spamming your own account.

You can just write a quick stored procedure to populate your db table with addresses such as

```
test1@mailinator.net, test2@mailinator.net etc.
```

Comment: @Alfred Yea I am afraid your best option would be to just write a small stored proc to do this. Probably would take less time then finiding and researching a tool. Good luck.